# How to create plugins that won't break on update

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've heard a lot about how you should write your own plugins (not sure if that's the right word), this way they won't break when a client updates WordPress. Am I getting the wrong idea from this? Are there any good resources for getting started on creating my own?

Comment: Plugins can "break" when a Wordpress update changes functionality the plugin depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. It's better to write a plugin than to alter the core. This way everything won't break when you update Wordpress.

See this link to get your started. http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin